# Getting Error when WSDL Access from SOAP UI

Tags: wsdl, soapui

When I am trying to access WSDL from in SOAP UI getting below Error:

> INFO:Error getting response;
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to refused

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the target to which the wsdl is trying to connect is not started or is not able to accept the requests. 
Does it have some kind of host based access mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

How to generate username token and password digest  for Webservice header

Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + password ) )